# Prove that $P(f^{-1}) = P(f)^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, permutations, kronecker-delta

> **Question:** Let $f$ be a permutation of the set {$1, 2, ..., n$} (a one-to-one function from the set to itself). Let $P(f)$ be the $n \times n$ matrix whose ($i, j$)-entry is $\delta_{i, f(j)}$. Show that $P(f^{-1}) = P(f)^{-1}$.

**Thoughts:** This should be pretty straightforward I think—nothing overly complicated, however, clearly I'm not entirely sure as I have decided to post the question here. Does it suffice to prove that $P(f)P(f^{-1}) = I_{n}$? If so, why exactly is that the case? As usual, I know where I need to end but need help getting started.

Comment: It does suffice to show $P(f) P(f^{-1}) = I_n$.

Comment: @angryavian could you remind my why it is that it suffices to show this?

Comment: This is how $P(f)^{-1}$ (the inverse of a matrix) is defined.

Comment: It suffices [because of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/81360). If $A,B$ are square matrices with $AB=I$, then $A$ and $B$ must be inverses.

Comment: Try to look at the function $v \rightarrow P(f)\cdot v$ and accordingly with with $P(f^{-1})$ and show that they invert one another